# Waiting for asynchronous code before populating array

Tags: angular, asynchronous

Trying to get `templates` with their `id`'s, but I'm having trouble coding it so that it waits for the return of the templates. See code below.
I know that I need to somehow wait for `getTemplateName` before populating my array, but asynchronous code is very difficult for me at the moment.

TS

```js
  templates: any = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = this.userService.getUser();
    this.syncService
      .getSyncDoc(this.user._id)
      .then(
        (res) =>
          (this.templates = res.Templates.map((template) => {
            console.log(this.templates);
            return this.templateService.getTemplateName(template);
          }))
      );
  }
```

template service

```js
  getTemplateName(templateId: string): Promise<any> {
    const selector = {
      Type: 'template',
      _id: templateId,
    };
    return this.dbService.find(selector).then((result: any) => {
      console.log(result.docs[0]);
      return result.docs[0];
    });
  }
```

html

```html
      <ion-item *ngFor="let template of templates">
        <ion-label>{{ template.Template_code }}</ion-label>
        <ion-radio slot="start" value="{{ template._id }}"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
```

Console
[image: Console]

App
[image: App]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Promise.all(ArrayOfPromises).then(DataArrayOfAllResults => doSomething())` which gets in an Array of Promises and returns a new Promise which will resolve when all Promises have finished.

something like that:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.user = this.userService.getUser();
this.syncService
  .getSyncDoc(this.user._id)
  .then(
    (res) =>
      { 
        Promise.all(
           res.Templates.map(template => this.templateService.getTemplateName(template))
        ).then(templates => this.templates = templates)
      })
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure where exactly I can implement that in my code. Could you tell me?